# Visual studio failed installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I tried to install Visual Studio Community 2015 on a fresh copy of windows 10, after having to reinstall it because of boot loop.

But i got a very strange error during the installation that i could not debug.

here's error message from the installer:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8KLV.jpg

and also error log

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_c5-heqG2ln0tHh17NGYDGOBOmJEV2Du9UILXmmzYyg/edit?usp=sharing

i tried several solutions on the web but nothing changed.

Any help?

TL;DR:
    VS installation tries to open nonexistent files?

Comment: Are you installing using the web installer or full iso?

Comment: i tried installing using web one, could not get my hands on iso from simple google-fu.

Comment: You can download the ISO file here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48146 (Click "Download", and an ISO option will show on the next page).

Comment: thanks, i will try it immediately.

Comment: installing from iso right now, had to do some registry cleaning because the failed installation created a lot of garbage blocking iso version from working. It seems that the original problem consisted in registry links leading to nonexistent bundle packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After parsing multiple error logs, one error was persistent across them which was caused by "custom culture", so i went to my region settings and changed format from English(Europe) to English(United Kingdom) and after that i got less errors.

I also had to do some registry cleaning because installation tried to use bundle packages that were not present on my PC. I wish this installer would try to reinstall them instead of just giving up.